# Avoid scrolling to the top in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` with `AutoScroll` set to `true` on tabpages. The tabpage contains a `RichTextBox`, which is bigger in height that the page, so vertical scrollbar appears on a `TabPage`. If I scroll the page down and then click on the `RichTextBox`, the page scrolls back to top. Any ideas on how to prevent such behaviour?

UPD: [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4505673/WindowsFormsApplication3.zip) is a sample project which can reproduce the issue. The issue occurs when the `RichTextBox` receives focus. E.g. scroll tabPage1 down, then select tabPage2, return to tabPage1 and click on the `RichTextBox`.

Comment: I just tried and couldn't recreate the issue.

Comment: @AccessDenied, I've updated the question and attached a sample project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a bit of struggling I've finally found a solution [here](http://seewinapp.blogspot.ru/2005/09/is-your-autoscroll-too-auto.html). All I had to do was to create my own class inherited from `TabPage` and override the `ScrollToControl` method, making it return `DisplayRectangle.Location`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to the fact that once you select the richTextBox and it is "out of sight" it goes to the current position(which in your case is not visible or at the top). If you select the richTextBox first and then scroll you will avoid this. One way you can do this is to `Select()` the richTextBox on application start.

Add this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Select();
        }
```

EDIT:

You can also add the Select() on TabIndexChanged as the behavior will reoccur if you change Tabs.

Comment: This doesn't help. Even if I select `RichTextBox` on `SelectedIndexChanged`, the tabpage scrolls to top. I suppose the `TabPage` scrolls the control into view on select, and I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Did you try it using on Event TabIndexChanged? The SelectedIndexChanged will not do you any good for this.

Comment: Yes, I did. The point is tabpage scrolls selected control into view. I've found a workaround [here](http://seewinapp.blogspot.ru/2005/09/is-your-autoscroll-too-auto.html), which worked for `RichTextBox`. Now I'm trying to make it work for `WebBrowser`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer while correct was difficult for me to initially understand without seeing the code. 
Perhaps this helps others.

```
public class CustomTabPage : System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
{
    protected override System.Drawing.Point ScrollToControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control activeControl)
    {
        //return base.ScrollToControl(activeControl);
        return activeControl.DisplayRectangle.Location;
    }
}
```

After defining your custom tabpage class, inherit now from this class in your form with your TabControl.

```
private CustomTabPage tpJobSetup;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem as you. I solved the problem by setting the AutoScrollMargin property of the tabPanel to 0. This way the page doesn´t scroll to the top.